# Autocompiling excel sheet from catalog

Tags: excel, catalog

I need to create an excel sheet where the user can select many products and for each one the corrispondent row will be automatically compiled with the product info inserted in another sheet (or something that represents the product catalog). How can I do?
Thank you!

Comment: I think we need a bit more explanation or some attempt at code before we can assist.

Comment: The problem is that I know how to use Excel but I've never used advanced features so I don't know what tools I need...macro? I have just to use REFs? In my idea there is a dropdown menu with all items present in catalog and when the user select one of those items the row will be completed with other item info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start simpler. Given that it sounds like you are still pretty new to the features of Excel and VBA in particular, I think you may want to read up a little on some of the options before diving into so large a project.

Below are some links I found from Googling some of the topics you asked about, I hope they help:

- Getting started with VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office
- Creating lists in cells: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGnvCKiOLM0
- VBA looping through worksheets: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook
- VBA looping through cells: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bq3N99mNPE

Once you have a rudimentary project put together with some code and are stuck, bring us those specific questions that have you stuck so we can help you work through them.

Good luck!